# How to create a object from refection but using dependency injection?

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection, inject

I have a set of classes which supports `javax.inject`. But now i need to invoke those classes using reflection.

```
o = clazz.newInstance();
...
method.invoke(o, parm1, param2 );
```

But instead of calling `newInstance()`, i like to know is there any possibility to get it as a injected object? and how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer which works in any place. But If you have a JNDI Context you can use the following to get the injected object. (But here you need to know the jndi name : eg : `java:module/PasswordDataRepository`)

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public static <T> T getValue(String jndiName, Class<T> type)
    {
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            return (T)ctx.lookup(jndiName);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```